# representation of a map with respect to 2 bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From Heffron, p.231

> Consider the two linear functions

$h:$ ${R}^3$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathcal{P}_2$ and ${g}: \mathcal{P}_2
 → M_{2x2}$

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a  \\ b  \\ c  \end{array} \right) \mapsto
 \space (a + b)x^2+(2a+2b)x+c$

$px^2+qx+r \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{ccc} p & p-2q \\ q & 0  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)$

> Use these bases for the spaces.

$B = \langle \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1  \\ 1  \\ 1  \end{array}
 \right) ,\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0  \\ 1  \\ 1  \end{array}
 \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0  \\ 0  \\ 1  \end{array}
 \right)\rangle$

$C=\langle1+x,1-x,x^2\rangle$

$D=\langle \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\  \end{array}
 \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \\  \end{array}
 \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 \\  \end{array}
 \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \\  \end{array}
 \right) \rangle$

> (a) Give the formula for the composition map g ◦ h: R3 → M2×2 derived
>   directly from the above definition.
>
> (b) Represent h and g with respect to the appropriate bases.

The answer to (a) is simple enough, however I'm having a horrible time trying to figure out how to find the representation of the map of h with respect to the bases B and C.

I understand the first step well enough, take the B1, B2, and B3, map them to $(a + b)x^2+(2a+2b)x+c$ and this gives you 3 equations. As I understand the meaning of representation in this context, what I'm supposed to produce is a matrix of coefficients used to express h as a linear combination of the basis vectors, but I'm not sure quite how I can use the basis C for this.

This is the given answer from the textbook:

$Rep_{B,C}(h)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 5/2 & 3/2 & 1/2 \\ -3/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0  \end{array}
 \right)$

I don't really understand where those coefficients are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $e_1, e_2, e_3$ the given vectors which consist a basis in $\mathbb R^3$ and $p_1(x)=1+x$, $p_2(x)=1-x$, $p_3(x)=x^2$ the polynomials that consist a basis of $\mathcal{P}_2$. Then we have:

$T(e_1) = T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right)\begin{array}[t]{l} = 2x^2 + 4x + 1 =  \frac{5}{2}\cdot(1+x) - \frac{3}{2}\cdot(1-x)+2x^2 \\\\ =\frac 52 \cdot p_1(x)  -\frac 32 \cdot p_2(x) + 2p_3(x).
\end{array}$

Similarly, we can find

$T(e_2) = T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right)\begin{array}[t]{l} = x^2 + 2x + 1 =  \frac{3}{2}\cdot(1+x) - \frac{1}{2}\cdot(1-x)+x^2 \\\\ =\frac 32 \cdot p_1(x)  -\frac 12 \cdot p_2(x) + 1\cdot p_3(x).
\end{array}.$

The same process is for $T(e_3)$.

Creating the transformation matrix with respect to the bases $B$ and $C$ is nothing more than inserting the coefficients as columns, i.e. the 2 first columns of the transformation will be:
$$[T]_h = \begin{bmatrix} 5/2 & 3/2 & * \\ -3/2 & -1/2 & * \\ 2 & 1 & * \end{bmatrix}.$$